# Accessing Facebook Likes and Interests with the old rest api

Tags: facebook, facebooker

In their recent changes, Facebook now links your likes and interests with community and fan pages. How can I retrieve this information using the old rest API and Facebooker. I tried things like this to get the music preferences :

```
facebook_session.user.music
```

but I get a blank string instead of the relevant connections. Is it mandatory to use the new Graph API in order to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this data can only be accessed via the Graph API.

Comment: Since no one else seems to have figured this out, I'll assume you're right. But that's not the answer I was hoping for! ;-)